# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Stack Exchange](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can I improve fuel economy by changing differential’s gear ratio?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6841/can-i-improve-fuel-economy-by-changing-differentials-gear-ratio)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is my transmission about to go?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6836/is-my-transmission-about-to-go)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Ford Fiesta - the colour of the water in the water container](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6666/ford-fiesta-the-colour-of-the-water-in-the-water-container)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How can I verify my brakes are decent when I can't trust the mechanic who worked on them?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6702/how-can-i-verify-my-brakes-are-decent-when-i-cant-trust-the-mechanic-who-worked)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Intermittent no crank issues](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6651/intermittent-no-crank-issues)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Evap code continues to warn after replacing the gas cap](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/evap-code-continues-to-warn-after-replacing-the-gas-cap)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How important are swing arm bushing pivot collars ? [ Honda CB400T Motorcycle ]](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/how-important-are-swing-arm-bushing-pivot-collars-honda-cb400t-motorcycle)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Would a snapped valve necessarily seize the engine?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6825/would-a-snapped-valve-necessarily-seize-the-engine)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Noisy blower fan in 92 Civic](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/noisy-blower-fan-in-92-civic)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is it possible to install power door lock on KIA Forte LX?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/6678/is-it-possible-to-install-power-door-lock-on-kia-forte-lx)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)